# Flash Mix Mouse and Gesture events

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, multi-touch, gesture

I have a flash application which handles only mouse events because it was firstly made for PC use so with a mouse and a keyboard.  Now I would like to add gesture events, and more precisely multitouch for zoom to use on tablets. I looked at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html, and added to my code the following :

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.events.GestureEvent;
import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;
import flash.events.GesturePhase;
```

In my init function :

```
Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM,onZoom);
```

And finally :

```
protected function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    //I tried both but no one works         
    //stage.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
    //stage.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
    stage.width *= e.scaleX;
    stage.height *= e.scaleY;
}
```

But it doesn't work. When I try to zoom with multitouch, it takes only the first touch and executes the mouse down and then mouse move event functions. So, I am wondering if it is possible to mix both mouse events and gesture events or if I have to redo my app replacing all mouse events with gesture events? Thanks.

Comment: Check how many input points can handle Your device , Multitouch.maxTouchPoints must be at least 2 . Anyway , I would advice You use of this: https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch

Comment: Finally, I made it worked using MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; instead of MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE; and then TOUCH_BEGIN ... . I have some little bugs because I had to change all mouse_down events into mouse_up (don't understand why) so I don't really get what I want for some functionalities, but the appli works well in general.